# Написать конструктор копирования

Tags: c++

Нужно написать конструктор копирования для класса, чтоб правильно присваивались значения в основной части кода

```
int main()
{
Str a = Str();
char *z = "abc"; //здесь компилятор ругается на указатель, не хочет ему ничего присваивать, делаю константой - не работает копирование
Str b = Str(z);
Str c(10);
return 0;}
```

Класс содержит только строку str
Моя попытка написать конструктор:

```
class Str    
{
char *str;
public:
Str()
{
    *str = '---';
};
Str(char* str)
{
    this->str = str;
}
~Str() {

}
Str(const Str & ref_str) 
{
    str = ref_str.str;
}

};
```

Comment: Добавьте класс целиком пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Добавьте ошибку компилятора. Там всё должно быть написано.

Comment: `char *z` -> `const char *z`. *"Моя попытка написать конструктор"* Попытка не считается. Вы написали такой же конструктор, который компилятор сгенерировал бы за вас.

Comment: Вам надо копировать **не указатель, а строку**. А компилятор ругается, что вы константный указатель (литерал) присваиваете неконстантному.

Comment: `'---'` - это вообще компилироваться стандартным компилятором не должно.

Answer (score 0):

Всё отлично работает с полем типа `const char *`: конструктор без аргументов, конструктор от `const char *`, конструктор копирования (его создаёт компилятор):

```
#include <iostream>

class Str    
{
private:
    const char *str;
public:
    Str() : str("---") {
    }
    explicit Str(const char *str) : str(str) {
    }
    friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Str &s);
};

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Str &s) {
    return os << s.str;
}

int main() {
    Str s1;
    std::cout << s1 << '\n';
    Str s2("Hi!");
    std::cout << s2 << '\n';
    s2 = s1;
    std::cout << s2 << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 temp.cpp && ./a.out 
> ---
> Hi!
> ---
> ```